# Where can one view the split between pretax, after-tax and Roth money in one's Vanguard 401(k) account?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan, roth-401k, vanguard

The best I could find is  https://retirementplans.vanguard.com -> Retirement plan participants -> Manage my money -> Manage my brokerage option, which gives the split between Roth money and pretax/after-tax money. But this doesn't give the split between pretax/after-tax money.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer](https://qr.ae/pN6XQl) from [David Dean](https://www.quora.com/profile/David-Dean-61):

1. Log on to your account at http://vanguard.com and access your employer plan.
2. Select "View Balance Details" under your account balance.
3. Select your plan name.
4. Select "Source of contribution" next to "View by."